# Problemas com Layout e CSS em IE 10 e 11

Tags: internet-explorer

estou editando umas páginas em C#. As páginas não bem simples porém sem muito efeito. O layout funciona muito bem em todos os navegadores inclusive o EDGE. porém no IE 10 e 11 tudo fica desconfigurado.
Além do CSS não pegar o HTML também sofre algumas alterações.

Estou utilizando o  e as tags abaixo

```
     <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
     <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE = edge, Chrome = 1" /> 
       <meta http-equiv = "x-ua-compatible" content = "IE = 11">
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE11" />
```

Porém não resolve o problema.

Segue imagens de apenas um dos itens que estão desalinhados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue link do sistema

https://eleicoes2018crmvmg.breleicoes.com/eleicoes/Login.aspx?tipins=1

Alguém já passou por isso??
Desde já agradeço!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub><sup>Nota: isto foi originalmente postado pela autora no corpo da pergunta.</sup></sub>

---

Bom, depois de peregrinar muito achei uma @media que resolveu o problema

```
 @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
       /* IE10+ specific styles go here */
   }
```

Basta inserir o css para o IE corrigindo os bugs nesta media. No meu caso resolveu!
Segue link do blog que achei a informação.
http://blog.simian.co/en/tips/internet-explorer-10-mobile-css-hacks-windows-phone/